# composer installation fails - jimmyjs/laravel-report-generator

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Trying to install **jimmyjs/laravel-report-generator**

Command:

```
composer require jimmyjs/laravel-report-generator
```

Output:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/code/BEAM$ composer require jimmyjs/laravel-report-generator
Using version ^1.1 for jimmyjs/laravel-report-generator
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: maatwebsite/excel[2.1.x-dev, 3.1.11].
    - Can only install one of: maatwebsite/excel[3.1.11, 2.1.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: maatwebsite/excel[2.1.x-dev, 3.1.11].
    - jimmyjs/laravel-report-generator 1.1.0 requires maatwebsite/excel ~2.1.0 
      -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[2.1.x-dev].
    - Installation request for jimmyjs/laravel-report-generator ^1.1 
      -> satisfiable by jimmyjs/laravel-report-generator[1.1.0].
    - Installation request for maatwebsite/excel (locked at 3.1.11, required as ^3.1) 
      -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[3.1.11].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I don't know if I'm misunderstanding the error? Says I can only have one maatwebsite (which is the case)?
`composer.json` current require which has maatwebsite (only instance) in it:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.1.3",
    "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "^0.4.4",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-amd64": "0.12.x",
    "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "0.12.x",
    "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.6",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
    "spatie/laravel-permission": "^2.13"
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need explicitly that version of Maatwebsite ("maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",), then you cant fix it cause `jimmyjs/laravel-report-generator` is not up to date with the new version of `maatwebsite`.

if you dont need the version 3 of `Maatwebsite`, you can remove the requirement for it and `jimmyjs/laravel-report-generator` will require the version `maatwebsite/excel 2.1.x-dev`.

wich might have some issue with your current version of php (7.1).

Better look for another alternative to `jimmyjs/laravel-report-generator` that uses the V3 of maatwebsite or something else

Or even better, do it yourself instead of using `jimmyjs/laravel-report-generator`. Maatwebsite v3 is really easy to use

Comment: I do need maatwebsite/excel 3 so, downgrading isnt an option. Will check out using maatwebsite to export to pdf instead then or something else entirely. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have looked it then your version is 3.1 `"maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",`

Now check your error

> Problem 1
>       - Can only install one of: maatwebsite/excel[2.1.x-dev, 3.1.11].

it says you need to install in `"maatwebsite/excel": "^2.1"`

Change and Add in your `composer.json` file:

```
"require": {
    "jimmyjs/laravel-report-generator": "^1.1",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "^2.1"
},
```

after, run this command in your command prompt  `composer update`

Comment: Can only install -one of- - I have one of them. The 3.1 version, which is listed there?